# How would a view request/receive data from an action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to implement a simple comment section in my page. I am also trying to make the code reusable by including it in a partial view. Here is how I envision the interaction between my partial view and the pertinent action method (call it Action A) inside my controller to occur. When the view gets called it receives an ID so it knows which comments to display. At that time it should call Action A to receive say 10 most recent comments. The view then displays this data together with an action link that would then call the same Action A for another 10 comments (somewhat similar to the comment section in facebook).

Since I am new to MVC, I'm not even sure if such communication between a view and a controller is the proper way to go about achieving this goal. Moreover, I don't know how to call an action method from a view for retrieving data purposes (asp.net code). Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to be able to pass a parameter in a link to the method for the 'page number' and use a query with `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanks for the reply. Is there any way though to retrieve data without actually displaying a link in the view? Eg the page loads, razor loads the data, then the view calls the action for some data.

Comment: Yes of course, but to get the next 10 comments you need a link/button (or be able to handle some client side event such as clicking a element) to be able to call the server and return the next group of records)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, I understand that part. Can you now tell me how to retrieve data without a link? Thank you

Comment: Have an ActionResult method that includes a parameter for the page number and returns a partial view of the comments. Then in the main view you can use `@Html.Action(yourActionName, yourControllerName, new { pageNumber = 1 })` to return the first 10 comments.